# Would else if be possible in some cases even if it isn't explicitly defined?

Tags: if-statement, parsing

While writing some code, I came across a question. If a hypothetical (C-style) programming language supported lossy curly braces, `if` and `else` but not `else if` (explicitly). Also it should it situations like

```c
if(a)
if(b)
f();
else
g();
```

group statements like

```c
if(a){
  if(b){
    f();
  }else{
    g();
  }
}
```

. So, (curly braces are unnecessary for this example)

```c
if(a){
  f1();
}else if(b){
  f2();
}else if(c){
  f3();
}else{
  f4();
}
```

would be grouped like

```c
if(a){
  f1();
}else{
  if(b){
    f2();
  }else{
    if(c){
      f3();
    }else{
      f4();
    }
  }
}
```

. I would like to check whether this would mean that in such hypothetical language `else if` would behave like in `C`. Thanks for reaching out.

Edit: To clarify, `lossy curly brackets`(I thought that it's spelled *loosy*) are something from a compiler warning from a while ago, when I wrote something like

```c
if(a)
    if(b)
        f1();
    else
        f2();
```

.

Another edit: Even though it's been pointed out that C might be my hypothetical language, I found a situation where a code would run in my hypothetical language but not in C:

```c
if(a) else
    f();
```

The previous edit addition: I saw something interesting in a StackOverflow answer today. It seems that the following snippet would the the valid adaptation of the hypothetical language code.

```c
if(a); else
f();
```

I've known of the `while(...);` but have not thought specifically of that beging used with `if`.

Comment: C doesn't have any special handling for `else if` IIRC, `else` and `if` just compose naturally so no special handling is required. Pretty sure C *is* your hypothetical language.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I also thought that initially, but quickly dismissed it because `else if` is being shown as a specific "branching block".

Comment: Shown *where*? Tutorials can describe `else if` as a special construct for beginners, but if the language can define `else` and `if` such that `else if` behaves as expected without the language defining it explicitly, there's no need for any such special definition.

Comment: How would anyone know what a hypothetical language should do? In C some say that curly braces should always be used, even if 'unnecessary'.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, that's (sort of) what wanted to check with this question.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question.  What are "lossy" curly braces?  What other situations are "like" the first example?  What rule(s) are you supposing would apply to produce the resulting logical groupings?  What behavior do you think `else if` has in C?

Comment: Which language are the examples written in? As with my braces comment, if in C the first snippet lacks indentation.

Comment: As mentioned in the question itself, this question is about a hypothetical C-style language. The necessary syntax details are contained in the question.

Comment: This depends entirely on how you define the grammar for your hypothetical language. As someone mentioned, however, C behaves as you describe: `else if` is really just an `else` followed by an `if`.

Comment: I think that I defined the grammar enough for that to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It would. As pointed out by the people in the comments, `C` doesn't have special handling for `else if`, but instead handles it like the hypothetical language.

Answer (score 0):

In the C programming language:

```c
else if(condition){
  statement;
}
```

Is strictly equivalent to:

```c
else{
  if(condition){
    statement;
  }
}
```